# How to read team chats with Keybase Chat API?

Tags: python, json, keybase

Whenever I use the following Keybase Chat API query:

```json
{
  "method": "read",
  "params": {
    "options": {
      "channel": {
        "name": "teamnamehere",
        "pagination": {
          "num": 1000
        },
        "members_type": "team"
        "topic_name": "channelnamehere"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get this result returned every time:

```json
{'error': {'code': 0, 'message': "invalid character 'm' looking for beginning of object key string"}}
```

This is the Python code to execute the query, with `q` being the query and `json_out` being a file that this error is written to:

```py
q = json.dumps(query)
cmd = "echo {} | keybase chat api > {}".format(q, json_out)
```

This works fine for the normal Chat API specifications between two users with the following:

```json
{
  "method": "read",
  "params": {
    "options": {
      "channel": {
        "name": "user1,user2",
        "pagination": {
          "num": 1000
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As far as I can tell, this confines to the standards set forth by the Chat API. Does anyone have any ideas on how to avoid this error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the problem, the Keybase API just wasn't very helpful with the provided error message.

You need to put quotes around the `{}` in the `echo` statement, like such:

```py
cmd = "echo '{}' | keybase chat api > {}".format(q, json_out)
```

Comment: Just Googled this a year later, found the right answer, then checked who posted it...

Comment: This "solution" has serious security problems. The purpose of the quotes is to stop the shell from munging your data, but single quotes aren't adequate for the purpose: a JSON string can contain literal quotes therein, reversing the literal quotes. A _slightly_ better thing to do is to use `shlex.quote()` to quote the data; a _much_ better thing to do is to use the subprocess module correctly so you aren't generating a string to be evaluated by a shell in the first place, bringing shell injection attacks completely out of the range of possibility.

Comment: That is to say, something like `subprocess.Popen(['keybase', 'chat', 'api'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=open(json_out, 'w')).communicate(q)`